# PHP Dynamic Method Chaining

Tags: php, loops, methods, chaining

How can I chain multiple methods together without knowing how many there will be? For instance how can I call this addMultiLink method more than once like a loop?

```
(new EntryField('products'))->addMultiLink($product_ids[0])
```

Basically I would want the result to be like this:

```
(new EntryField('products'))->addMultiLink($product_ids[0])->addMultiLink($product_ids[1])->addMultiLink($product_ids[2])
```

Comment: No, it was more of a question on how to do it in a loop

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry for flagging.

Answer (score 1):

In your `addMultiLink` return `$this`:

```
public function addMultiLink($argument) 
{
    // your code here

    return $this;
}
```

But as I can see you pass elements of array in your function per call.
Maybe it's better to rewrite `addMultiLink` and consider it's argument as array? Or check if it is array or some integer value:

```
public function addMultiLink($argument) 
{
    if (is_array($argument)) {
        // do a foreach loop for example
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_entry_field = (new EntryField('products'));
    foreach($product_ids as $product_id) {
        $product_entry_field->addMultiLink($product_id);
    }
```